# Using an expression with subscript with overset command

Tags: subscripts, overset

I have the following document. As you see after compiling, the subscript `b` is almost lies on the arrow. It should be upper. What are the way to fix it. An alternative solution is also welcomed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$X\overset{f_b}{\rightarrow}Y$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use the `\xrightarow` command from the mathtools package.

Comment: `\xrightarrow` is also part of `amsmath`: `$X\xrightarrow{f_b}Y$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution: use the `\xrightarrow` command. (Thanks to egreg and Steven B. Segletes.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$X\xrightarrow{f_b}Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Let me wait to have alternative solutions before accepting your answer.

Comment: @egreg Mille grazie!